# KeyboardDidHide function called when first tap on react native TextInput in IOS

Tags: react-native

**My code as below**

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}

_keyboardDidHide() {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
}

<TextInput
        placeholder="text 1"
        onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ text1:text }) }}
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        value={this.state.text1} />
```

It is working fine in android but in IOS it occurs problem. my TextInput doesn't get focused on first Tap. Suddenly keyboard get closed and my input's lost focus. please help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with this function ? I have tried this in my App - iOS and it working fine right now.

Comment: This problem has been resolved. it was occurring because simulator's keyboard was disabled. i enabled keyboard of simulator and problem resolved and also thanks for reply!